# C program to display the number if it is a power of 2 in an array

Tags: c, pow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int num,i;
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int a[num];
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<num+1; i++){
        if (pow(2,i) == a[i]){
            printf("%d\n",a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a program that displays an integer in an array if it is a power of two. ex; an array contains the integer (1,2,4,9) it will print 1,2 and 4 only.

What is wrong with this code? It works on some test cases, but on most it doesn't.

Comment: I haven't checked your code but in the array `(1,2,4,9)` the powers of 2 are `1,2,4` so I don't know what your problem is.  For diagnosis it's generally better to consider erroneous outputs, but you show us none of those.

Comment: The [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) function is a *floating point* function. As such it will lead to rounding problems. For powers of two, all you need are integers and *bitwise shift*.

Comment: `i<num+1` - for a VLA clearly defined as magnitude `num`. Um....

Comment: Oh and I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). That last loop condition, are you sure about that one?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude last time i checked rubber ducks were out of stock. might be the reason we are seing such mediocre questions here lately.

Answer (score 3):

If `value` is a power of two, only one bit is set:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

bool is_pow_of_2(unsigned value)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (unsigned shift = 0; shift < sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT; ++shift) {
        if (value & 1 << shift)  // test if bit shift is set
            ++count;
        if (count > 1)      // if there a more than one bits set in value
            return false;  //  it cannot be a power of 2
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Plan B:

```
bool is_pow_of_2(signed value)
{
    if(value <= 0)
        return false;

    // ...
```

Comment: this method is really nice, but can you add comments to help us understand what happens here ?

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Added comments.

Comment: Nitpick - The OP is dealing with signed numbers, whereas this solution considers only unsigned numbers. Was just wondering... what if just the sign bit is set?

Comment: @babon Have you ever seen a negative power? O.O

Comment: @Swordfish What if the user wants to check with `-128` or `10000000` in bin? `-128` is not a power of `2` although just a single bit is set. `2` raised to `-7` doesn't give you `-128`.

Comment: @babon The function only takes unsigned values for a reason.

Comment: @Swordfish and that is exactly the thing I pointed out in my first / "Nitpick" comment. Seems like you've lost your rubber duckie ;)

Comment: @babon what is the problem with validating that value is in a range the function excepts before passing it \*hands-back-rubber-duckie\*

Comment: @Swordfish :) Yep, that'll work. But your answer does not include that. Let's leave it here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a number is a power of `n` with a recursive function :

```
function isPowOfn(int n, int number) {
    return (number == 1 ? TRUE : (number % n != 0 ? FALSE : isPowOfn(n, number / n)));
}
```

or (as suggested by WhozCraig)

```
function isPowOfn(int n, int number) {
    return value == 1 || (value % n == 0 && isPowOfn(n, number / n))
}
```

#### Input-output examples :

```
in: 2, 6  
processing: 3  
out: FALSE
```

---

```
in: 2, 16  
processing: 8 - 4 - 2 - 1  
out: TRUE
```

---

```
in: 2, 162  
processing: 81
out: FALSE
```

---

```
in: 3, 81
processing: 27 - 9 - 3 - 1
out: TRUE
```

---

```
in: 5, 244140625
processing: 48828125 - 9765625 - 1953125 - 390625 - 78125 - 15625 - 3125 - 625 - 125 - 25 - 5 - 1
out: TRUE
```

---

```
in: 4, 67957741992
processing: 16989435498
out: FALSE
```

Comment: Just realized that. I wanted to use a function to avoid double-ternary. Fixed

Comment: You can anyway.

Comment: Single line: `return value == 1 || (value % n == 0 && isPowOfn(n,value / n));`

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Function to check if x is power of 2*/
bool isPowerOfTwo (int x) 
{ 
  /* First x in the below expression is for the case when x is 0 */
  return x && (!(x&(x-1))); 
}
```

**Explanation**: A power of 2 has only 1 bit set. If we subtract 1 from a power of 2 then all unset bits after the only set bit become set; and the set bit becomes unset.

If `x` is a power of 2, `x&(x-1)` will be 0. `(!(x&(x-1)))` will be 1. And the return expression will be 1.
The logical AND (`&&`) of this expression with `x` is to ensure that this will not be true if `x` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The other methods proposed to test if a number is a power of two make assumptions about the representation of numbers. This should be avoided. Always write for clarity and portability.

```
bool is_power_of_2 (int n)
{
    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        n = n / 2;
    }

    return (n == 1);
}
```

Comment: Rumors have it that two's-complement will eventually become standard in C++20.